# Perl: open-ing a pipe for writing but program is not "waiting" for STDIN

Tags: perl, pipe, stdout, stdin

I am trying to run a program from a perl script.
I redirect STDOUT and STDERR to two different files.
The program I am running asks for a password that I try to print to the process handle but that doesn't work as the program immediately prints an authentication error warning me that I didn't write anything to STDIN.

The code I am using is similar to this:

```
my $s = qq(some_program > someprogram.out 2> someprogram.err);
open(my $f, "|$s") or die "Couldn't run program: $! $?";
# print `cat someprogram.out`; # An error has already been printed here!
print $f "password\n";
close $f or die "$!: $?";
```

I have run this in the perl debugger and noticed that when the debugger runs the open line, I can run the commented out print line and the error is already in the output file.

So, what am I forgetting to do in order for this to work?
How do I tell open to "wait for STDIN"?

---UPDATE!

I did a test like this in the command line:

```
echo password | some_program
```

and the authentication error was printed. So it looks like **some_program** is really not reading from STDIN but from tty.

Is there a way to print to tty so the program can read the password from there in Perl?

Comment: Are you sure `some_program` is reading the password from standard input? If `some_program` is ssh, to give one of many examples, it is probably trying to read from the terminal, which is not necessarily the same thing as standard input.

Comment: Hi, mob. I am not sure about that but it looks like this is the case. What options do I have?

Comment: Ssh won't play nicely with your pipe - Use Expect.

Comment: @mob @Len What I meant to say with "it looks like this is the case" is that `some_program` is not reading from STDIN and doing it from the terminal; not that it was ssh. 

I did a test like this in the command line: `echo password | some_program` and the authentication error appears. So the program is not reading from STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

Considering `some_program` is a bash script (Shell) which accepts password on its command line, this can be done using `system` calls in perl. The system call, i.e. the program execution within Perl will not halt for the password, the best bet is to ask user for password before you call the program using a system call. Use backticks to perform system calls, something like below;

```
my $outfile="/path/to/someprogram.out";
my $errfile="/path/to/someprogram.err";
print "Enter password:\n";
$passwd=<>;
print "some_program $passwd\n";
`some_program $passwd > $outfile 2> $errfile`;
```

OR use `system();`

```
my $outfile="/path/to/someprogram.out";
my $errfile="/path/to/someprogram.err";
print "Enter password:\n";
$passwd=<>;
my $command="some_program $passwd > $outfile 2> $errfile";
print "$command\n";
system($command);
```